# Selenium returned JavaScript error (UnexpectedJavaScriptError)

Tags: c#, selenium

When I run this code inside mstest testmethod using c#...

```
IWebDriver iWebDriver = new InternetExplorerDriver();

WebDriverBackedSelenium webDriverBackedSelenium = new WebDriverBackedSelenium(iWebDriver, "http://localhost:53157");

webDriverBackedSelenium.Start();

webDriverBackedSelenium.WaitForCondition("selenium.browserbot.getUserWindow().$.active == 0", "5000");
```

I get a Javascript error (UnexpectedJavaScriptError) yet I have seen example after example that this is the way to go.

As an additional peice of information I have tested that jquery-1.7.1 is loaded and usable.  I have even tested within the webpage without selenium just using an inline script to see if $.active would work and it does.

Can anyone tell what I'm doing wrong here?  Any guess would be welcome.

Comment: Shouldn't the javascript be selenium.browserbot.getCurrentWindow().$.active

Comment: I have tried both selenium.browserbot.getCurrentWindow().$.active AND selenium.browserbot.getUserWindow().$.active with both returning the same error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you're using WebDriverBackedSelenium, you have a lot more latitude with the types of script you can execute. Additionally, you don't need to use "selenium.browserbot", and indeed, the browserbot object may not even be loaded by WebDriverBackedSelenium. If you try the following, it should work:

```
IWebDriver iWebDriver = new InternetExplorerDriver();
WebDriverBackedSelenium webDriverBackedSelenium = new WebDriverBackedSelenium(iWebDriver, "http://localhost:53157");
webDriverBackedSelenium.Start();
webDriverBackedSelenium.Open("relative/path/to/jQueryPage.html");
webDriverBackedSelenium.WaitForCondition("$.active == 0", "5000");
```

Comment: Does the .Open() just need to point at the path of the web page being used? OR Does it need to point at the jQuery library I am using to execute $.active?

Comment: The sample code above assumes that the web page being used already loads jQuery in its HTML source. The `.Open()` call should simply open the page that you're using.

Answer (score 0):

You may try using `IJavaScriptExecutor` and use while loop and try wait till the condition matches.

You may want to see documentation here

http://selenium.googlecode.com/svn-history/r15240/trunk/docs/api/dotnet/html/AllMembers_T_OpenQA_Selenium_IJavaScriptExecutor.htm

Also remember that value return by `IJavaScriptExecutor` is an object. You may have to cast it to string before making comparison.